# I can't seem to get my texture(UV?) to scale for my desired effect without the texture warping

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I'm trying to texture an arcade cabinet with an 80's style minimalist neon line art (I'm not a good artist so my lines are terrible). When I try to resize the UV or anything else to get my texture file to "zoom" the texture to create a perspective effect, the straight lines start to warp and deform. I have tried to separate the faces that cause an issue and give them a different version of the image texture, but then I can't get anything to line up. Basically the texture should look similar to spider-man logo with the legs being longer at the bottom (this isn't a spider). I tried to recreate what I need in photoshop to provide some type of reference for what I need, but I'm not good with photoshop. Enjoy, have a laugh and thanks for any help.

[image: render result]

This is the output.

[image: desire]

This is more the desired result. I would like the texture to gradually scale and wrap around the sides at the bottom.  The center above the coin slots are the trouble area.

Blend file if needed:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Faces are made of triangles, quads are made of 2 triangles, if you begin to deform the UV face in the *UV Editor* (or in the 3D view if the *Correct Face Attributes* option is disabled) it will tweak these triangles and you'll begin to see this triangulation effect:

[image]

So I guess the more convenient, instead of deforming the UV, will be to prepare the image so that it directly fits your needs. Or subdivide the mesh and deform it, the more subdivided it will be the less you'll see the triangulation, but the more it will be difficult to handle:

[image]

Comment: thanks. I'll give this a try. I had already tried the subdivide thing but I will try all your examples again and hopefully have better luck.